# JBOD hard drives report incorrect size

Tags: storage-area-network, netapp, fibre-channel

I am trying to setup a netapp ds14 to use with 6 and 8tb SATA drives
I got FC to SATA interposer boards and now all the drives are correctly identified and visible, however the capacity that I see is only 1.5tb for all of the drives

What am I missing?

here are some logs

```
sg_scan -i
/dev/sg0: scsi6 channel=0 id=0 lun=0
    XYRATEX   RS-1402-SA-XNS1   3034 [rmb=0 cmdq=1 pqual=0 pdev=0xd] 
/dev/sg1: scsi6 channel=0 id=1 lun=0
    XYRATEX   RS-1402-SA-XNS1   3034 [rmb=0 cmdq=1 pqual=0 pdev=0xd] 
/dev/sg2: scsi6 channel=0 id=2 lun=0
    WDC       WD60EDAZ-11U78SX  0A80 [rmb=0 cmdq=1 pqual=0 pdev=0x0] 
/dev/sg3: scsi6 channel=0 id=3 lun=0
    WDC       WD60EDAZ-11U78SX  0A80 [rmb=0 cmdq=1 pqual=0 pdev=0x0]
```

```
sginfo /dev/sg2
INQUIRY response (cmd: 0x12)
----------------------------
Device Type                        0
Vendor:                    WDC
Product:                   WD60EDAZ-11U78SX
Revision level:            0A80
```

```
sg_format --resize --count=-1 /dev/sg2
    WDC       WD60EDAZ-11U78SX  0A80   peripheral_type: disk [0x0]
Mode Sense (block descriptor) data, prior to changes:
  Number of blocks=3130979503 [0xba9ef4af]
  Block size=512 [0x200]
Resize operation seems to have been successful
```

```
sg_readcap -v /dev/sg2
    read capacity(10) cdb: 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Read Capacity results:
   Last LBA=3130979502 (0xba9ef4ae), Number of logical blocks=3130979503
   Logical block length=512 bytes
Hence:
   Device size: 1603061505536 bytes, 1528798.6 MiB, 1603.06 GB
```

Comment: WD60EDAZ is an AF disk. try checking if your disk is 4kn or 512e by running `smartctl -i /dev/sg2 | grep block`. if you're using this as a NAS/SAN storage, you probably want 4kn.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your controller and all other hardware devices support larger drive sizes greater than 2TB.  You do not mention the controller, firmware, etc. for me to look up the specification sheets, however it seems highly likely that your controller does not support large drives.  Also all firmware and drivers/software must support the larger drive sizes.

You will commonly find this described online as the 2TB limit, 2.2TB limit, or 32-bit LBA limit amongst other names.  With support for 32-bit logical block addressing (LBA) a device cannot see more then 2TiB/2.2TB of capacity.  The size you report appears to be the 32-bit truncation of a 34-bit LBA capacity that matches the 6TB you are expecting.

`(32-bit)  0xba9ef4ae * 512 = 1,603,061,505,024`
`(34-bit) 0x2ba9ef4ae * 512 = 6,001,108,016,128`

It would appear the controller does not support large LBA so the loss of the most significant bits is wrapping the drive size from 6TB to 1.6TB as you have seen.

Generally this is a permanent hardware limitation.  In some cases it is possible to update firmware, drivers, partitioning scheme, or other factors, however that is beyond the scope here as it would be specific to your entire configuration.  "Something" in your configuration is truncating the capacity to 32-bit.

Comment: I searched up a few DS14 links which lead me to the conclusion they may have maxed out at 600GB drives.